# Resultado ao converter de minutos para horas

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma query em que tenho um exemplo que dá o resultado correto e no outro não ao converter de minutos para horas.

1º exemplo em minutos:

```
SELECT  A.Colaborador,
        SUM(A.`Horas Consumidas`) AS `Total Horas`    
FROM
(SELECT centrodb.utentes.codigoutente,
        centrodb.utentes.nome,
        centrodb.utentes.descricaovalencia,
        centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`DataRegisto`,     
        centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`Data`,
        Inicio,
        Fim,
        centrodb.colaboradores.Nome AS Colaborador,
        TIME_TO_SEC(TimeDiff(TIME_FORMAT(Fim,'%H:%i'), TIME_FORMAT(Inicio,'%H:%i')))/60 AS `Horas Consumidas`    
FROM centrodb.registoFisioterapia LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.utentes    
ON centrodb.utentes.Id = centrodb.registoFisioterapia.utente    
LEFT OUTER JOIN colaboradores    
ON centrodb.colaboradores.codigo = centrodb.registoFisioterapia.Nome    
where centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`Data` between '2018-04-26' And '2018-05-8' AND centrodb.colaboradores.Nome = 'TÂNIA LOPES') AS A    
GROUP BY A.Colaborador
```

Resultado: 1650 minuots

1º exemplo convertido a horas:

```
SELECT  A.Colaborador,
        TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(A.`Horas Consumidas`)),'%i:%s') AS `Total Horas`

FROM
(SELECT centrodb.utentes.codigoutente,
        centrodb.utentes.nome,
        centrodb.utentes.descricaovalencia,
        centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`DataRegisto`,     
        centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`Data`,
        Inicio,
        Fim,
        centrodb.colaboradores.Nome AS Colaborador,
        TIME_TO_SEC(TimeDiff(TIME_FORMAT(Fim,'%H:%i'), TIME_FORMAT(Inicio,'%H:%i')))/60 AS `Horas Consumidas`    
FROM centrodb.registoFisioterapia LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.utentes    
ON centrodb.utentes.Id = centrodb.registoFisioterapia.utente    
LEFT OUTER JOIN colaboradores    
ON centrodb.colaboradores.codigo = centrodb.registoFisioterapia.Nome    
where centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`Data` between '2018-04-26' And '2018-05-8' AND centrodb.colaboradores.Nome = 'TÂNIA LOPES') AS A    
GROUP BY A.Colaborador
```

Resultado: 27:30

**2º exemplo em minutos onde dá as horas erradas:**

```
SELECT  A.Colaborador,
        SUM(A.`Horas Consumidas`) AS `Total Horas`    
FROM
(SELECT centrodb.utentes.codigoutente,
        centrodb.utentes.nome,
        centrodb.utentes.descricaovalencia,
        centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`DataRegisto`,     
        centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`Data`,
        Inicio,
        Fim,
        centrodb.colaboradores.Nome AS Colaborador,
        TIME_TO_SEC(TimeDiff(TIME_FORMAT(Fim,'%H:%i'), TIME_FORMAT(Inicio,'%H:%i')))/60 AS `Horas Consumidas`    
FROM centrodb.registoFisioterapia LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.utentes    
ON centrodb.utentes.Id = centrodb.registoFisioterapia.utente    
LEFT OUTER JOIN colaboradores    
ON centrodb.colaboradores.codigo = centrodb.registoFisioterapia.Nome    
where centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`Data` between '2018-03-26' And '2018-04-25' AND centrodb.colaboradores.Nome = 'TÂNIA LOPES') AS A    
GROUP BY A.Colaborador
```

Resultado: 3840 minutos

2º exemplo convertido a horas:

```
SELECT  A.Colaborador,
        TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(A.`Horas Consumidas`)),'%i:%s') AS `Total Horas`    
FROM
(SELECT centrodb.utentes.codigoutente,
        centrodb.utentes.nome,
        centrodb.utentes.descricaovalencia,
        centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`DataRegisto`,     
        centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`Data`,
        Inicio,
        Fim,
        centrodb.colaboradores.Nome AS Colaborador,
        TIME_TO_SEC(TimeDiff(TIME_FORMAT(Fim,'%H:%i'), TIME_FORMAT(Inicio,'%H:%i')))/60 AS `Horas Consumidas`    
FROM centrodb.registoFisioterapia LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.utentes    
ON centrodb.utentes.Id = centrodb.registoFisioterapia.utente    
LEFT OUTER JOIN colaboradores    
ON centrodb.colaboradores.codigo = centrodb.registoFisioterapia.Nome    
where centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`Data` between '2018-03-26' And '2018-04-25' AND centrodb.colaboradores.Nome = 'TÂNIA LOPES') AS A    
GROUP BY A.Colaborador
```

Resultado: 04:00, mas devia ter como resultado 64:00.

Alguém me consegue ajudar a resolver este problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não se trata apenas de um erro no código, mas também de uma pequena confusão com o resultado da função `SEC_TO_TIME` usada para obter o resultado. Esta confusão é em parte causada pelo fato de, tal como 1650 minutos correspondem a 27h30m, também 1650 segundos correspondem a 27m30s.

Se não prestar bem atenção parece que se trata da mesma unidade de tempo. Não ajuda aqui o fato da máscara `'%i:%s'` esconder a componente hora do resultado final.

Vamos então por partes: Na sua subquery calcula a diferença entra o inicio e o fim da sessão de fisioterapia. Esta diferença é convertida em segundos pela função TIME_TO_SEC e depois convertida em minutos. Aqui:

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TimeDiff(TIME_FORMAT(Fim,'%H:%i'), TIME_FORMAT(Inicio,'%H:%i')))/60
```

No SELECT exterior, soma os minutos de cada colaborador mas volta a usar a função SEC_TO_TIME que espera um input em segundos e não em minutos. Aqui está o problema.

Sabendo isto, é fácil perceber que no resultado a que chama "1º exemplo convertido a horas" vem 0h27m30s. E no resultado a que chama "2º exemplo convertido a horas" vem 04:00.

```
SEC_TO_TIME(3840) = 3840 / 60 / 60 = !!64!! / 60 ~= 1h04m00
```

O problema é que a sua máscara faz com que o resultado final apenas mostre 04:00. Sem a máscara, iria facilmente perceber onde está o erro.

Veja o [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ebb114/33). Fica aqui também uma alternativa ao Fiddle (que mais uma vez está em baixo) [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler)

Agora que percebemos o porque dos vários resultados (eu espero, porque a explicação está um pouco confusa), para corrigir o seu código e obter o total de horas para cada colaborador pode por exemplo, remover a conversão para minutos e trabalhar sempre com os segundos e só no final converter para TIME.

Aplicando ao seu código (note que a função SUM passou para o interior uma vez que não estava a usar nenhum dos outros campos, para simplificar um pouco), ficaria:

```
SELECT  A.Colaborador,
        SEC_TO_TIME(Total_Segundos_Consumidos) AS `Total Horas`    
FROM
(
    SELECT centrodb.colaboradores.Nome AS Colaborador,
           SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TimeDiff(TIME_FORMAT(Fim,'%H:%i'), TIME_FORMAT(Inicio,'%H:%i')))) AS Total_Segundos_Consumidos    
      FROM centrodb.registoFisioterpia 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN colaboradores    
        ON centrodb.colaboradores.codigo = centrodb.registoFisioterapia.Nome    
     WHERE centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`Data` between '2018-03-26' AND '2018-04-25' 
       AND centrodb.colaboradores.Nome = 'TÂNIA LOPES'
     GROUP BY centrodb.colaboradores.Nome 
) AS A
```

Comment: Só tenho um problema ao mostrar o resultado, mostra desta forma: `64h 0.0000m` e devia mostrar: `64:00`

Comment: @Iniciante, pode experimentar CONCAT(FLOOR(Total_Minutos_Consumidos/60),':',MOD(Total_Minutos_Consumidos,60),'0')

Comment: Mesmo assim, na parte de minutos fica desta forma: `64:0.00000`

Comment: E se não converter no interior para minutos, apenas somar os segundos, e fizer apenas SEC_TO_TIME(Total_Minutos_Consumidos) no exterior?

Comment: Está a dizer assim: `CONCAT(FLOOR(SEC_TO_TIME(Total_Minutos_Consumidos/60)),':',MOD(SEC_TO_TIME(Total_Minutos_Consumidos,60),'0'))`

Comment: Editei a resposta. A ideia é não converter nunca para minutos e no exterior, apenas usar uma vez SEC_TO_TIME